# Whole bunch of errors on WP website - media upload, edit slugs, edit screen not working

Tags: uploads, errors, media

I am having a problem which I didn't meet before. I took a client website for just a small bunch of modifications, so I wasn't there when WordPress was installed or when the theme was developed. 
But when I enter the admin area, I can not upload media, I can not edit slugs, and on top of all, the "edit" screen for pages and posts is not working: I can't see the text I am typing, I can't see the format buttons, I can't use the visual/html buttons (please see attached). The website in question uses Genesis framework along with a Genesis theme child. It has a bunch of plugins installed. Now I am asking you, in your experience, what could cause these problems?
- WordPress was installed wrong
- A plugin is causing the problems
- It has something to do with Genesis
- ...?

[problem screenshot](http://www.girlscancode.com/problem-screenshot.jpg)

What do you think?

Comment: Some poorly written themes or plugins replace the default jQuery URI with something else. Have you checked that?

Comment: Using Google Chrome or a similar browser, load up the console / error screen to try and identify any errors. In Google Chrome, click on the wrench > Tools > Developer Tools. Then click Console on the screen which appears at the bottom of the screen. Make a note of any errors in red, and if they include /wp-content/plugins, disable those plugins and identify whether the issue is resolved. Alternatively, disable plugins one by one, again identifying at which point the issue is resolved. This is more trial and error, but should point you in the right direction as to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but some extra and different plugins, after 2 days of disabling plugins one by one, checking theme files etc, etc, I decide to start from 0, Backup database, (all post, etc,~) and just re install. Not a beauty, but it will solve the problem faster than you searching for the needle on the haystack.

Possible quick solution -
Reinstall all including Plugins.

Comment: Nah guys, I've tried everything, at least 100 different "solutions". I've disabled ALL plugins, I've removed wp-admin and wp-includes and uploaded them again, I've tried define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); Every piece of solution on google has been tried. It killed my whole weekend unfortunately. I think I will just have to reinstall...

Comment: @Gabriela, before reinstall, I forgot to mention, save a copy of your plugins. Upload and use a fresh copy of each plugin, and if you are really interested in finding where is the problem, remove one by one each plugin and replace with the back-up ones, each time checking that all works until you find the problem.